# Design pattern for "site wide" ViewModel variables

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, knockout.js

Im searching for a smart design pattern for loading site wide variables into the ViewModel for multiple views in the project (in a DRY way). Fuzzy question, an example may clarify things:

In my project I have a partial view that displays regular- and error messages from the server on the client. The messages are bound with Knockout bindings like this:

```html
<p class="message" data-bind="visible: (message.length > 0), text='message'"></p>
```

This means I have to add the same code into every ViewModel:

```
viewModel.message = ko.observable("some message from server or none");
```

This is not DRY!

How does one solve this in a smart way? Is there any smart design pattern out there for this scenario?

I already know a couple of "not so good options", so please keep to the good options. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can extend models by using `apply`.  Other methods for extending can be used, but this is short and sufficient for Knockout ViewModels.

### [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LbtnQ/)

Both A and B extend Base.  You can extend multiple classes (or Interfaces) on one ViewModel, and anything that extends a base, also gets the members of their base, and so on.

In this case our Base has an `error` observable.  We could also give it some functions for interacting with our server, etc.

```
function Base(){
    var self = this;
    self.error = ko.observable('No Error');
}
```

`A` extends `Base`, and can access error without defining it.

```
function A(){
    var self = this; Base.apply(self, arguments);

    self.greeting = ko.observable('Hello');

    // Change the error
    self.error('A has an error');
}
```

`B` also extends `Base`, however only uses the observable in HTML (see the fiddle).

```
function B(){
    var self = this; Base.apply(self, arguments);

    self.data = new Date;
}

ko.applyBindings({
    a: new A,
    b: new B
});
```